# Timing in ArrayFire

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpgpu, nvidia, arrayfire

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of simple GPU elementwise matrix operations with ArrayFire.

In particular, considering

```
int N1 = something;
int N2 = something;

array A_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
array B_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
array C_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
array D_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
```

I would like to perform the timing of the following instruction

```
D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
```

I'm using two approaches. The first one is

```
timer  time_last;
time_last = timer::start();

D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;

double elapsed = timer::stop(time_last);
printf("elapsed time using start and stop = %g ms \n",1000.*elapsed);
```

The second one is defining the following function

```
void timing_test()
{
    int N1 = something;
int N2 = something;

    array A_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array B_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array C_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array D_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);

    D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
}
```

and then calling

```
printf("elapsed time using timeit %g ms \n", 1000.*timeit(timing_test));
```

I have obtained the following results:

`(N1,N2)=(256,256)`  first approach = `0.0456ms`  second approach = `0.264ms`

`(N1,N2)=(512,512)`  first approach = `0.0451ms`  second approach = `0.264ms`

`(N1,N2)=(1024,1024)`  first approach = `0.0457ms`  second approach = `0.263ms`

`(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`  first approach = `0.127ms`  second approach = `0.265ms`

I'm also using the following "hand-coded" version of the expression according to

```
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

eval_matrix_wrap_handcoded(A_D,B_D,C_D,D_D,N1*N2);

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
__global__ inline void evaluation_matrix_handcoded(T1 *A_D, T2 *B_D, T3 *C_D, T4 *D_D, int NumElements)
{
    const int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i < NumElements) D_D[i]=A_D[i]+B_D[i]+C_D[i]+3.;
}

__host__ void eval_matrix_wrap_handcoded(double *A_D, double *B_D, double *C_D, double *D_D, int NumElements)
{
    dim3 dimGrid(iDivUp(NumElements,dimBlock.x));
    evaluation_matrix_handcoded<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(A_D,B_D,C_D,D_D,NumElements);
}
```

obtaining the following

`(N1,N2)=(256,256)`  `0.0897ms`

`(N1,N2)=(512,512)`  `0.339ms`

`(N1,N2)=(1024,1024)`  `1.3ms`

`(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`  `5.37ms`

The strange thing is that

1. The results of the two approaches are different. This could be due to a function call overhead, but it is anyway strange that this overhead changes when `(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`.
2. The results of the two approaches are almost independent on the matrix sizes.
3. The results are much different as compared to a "hand-coded" version of the expression (I'm assuming a library should have a productivity-performance trade-off).

Note that, before any operation, I'm warming up the GPU using the code

```
array test1(1,5);
test1(0,0)=1;
test1(0,1)=2;
test1(0,2)=3;
test1(0,3)=4;
test1(0,4)=5;
```

Could someone help me interpreting the above results? Thanks.

**EDIT FOLLOWING PAVAN'S ANSWER**

First method modified to

```
timer  time_last;
time_last = timer::start();

D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
D_D.eval();
af::sync();

double elapsed = timer::stop(time_last);
printf("elapsed time using start and stop = %g ms \n",1000.*elapsed);
```

Second method modified to

```
void timing_test()
{
    int N1 = something;
    int N2 = something;

    array A_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array B_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array C_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);
    array D_D = constant(1.,N1*N2,1,f64);

    D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
    D_D.eval();
}
```

However, the timing now is

```
`(N1,N2)=(256,256)`  first approach = `14.7ms`  second approach = `2.04ms`

`(N1,N2)=(512,512)`  first approach = `14.3ms`  second approach = `2.04ms`

`(N1,N2)=(1024,1024)`  first approach = `14.09ms`  second approach = `2.04ms`

`(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`  first approach = `16.47ms`  second approach = `2.04ms`
```

and I still have different timings and independent on the vectors size.

If I modify the first method to

```
D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
D_D.eval();

timer  time_last;
time_last = timer::start();

D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
D_D.eval();
af::sync();

double elapsed = timer::stop(time_last);
printf("elapsed time using start and stop = %g ms \n",1000.*elapsed);
```

namely, I "increase" the GPU warm-up stage, the I obtain, for the first method,

```
`(N1,N2)=(256,256)`  `0.19ms`

`(N1,N2)=(512,512)`  `0.42ms`

`(N1,N2)=(1024,1024)`  `1.18ms`

`(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`  `4.2ms`
```

which appears more reasonable to me since the timing depend on the data size and is closer to hand-coding.

**SECOND EDIT**
To summarize: I have accounted for the answer and the comment and, for the first approach, I'm using

```
D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
D_D.eval();

timer  time_last;
af::sync();
time_last = timer::start();

D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
D_D.eval();
af::sync();

double elapsed = timer::stop(time_last);
printf("elapsed time using start and stop = %g ms \n",1000.*elapsed);
```

I'm obtaining the following (new) results:

```
`(N1,N2)=(256,256)`  `0.18ms`

`(N1,N2)=(512,512)`  `0.30ms`

`(N1,N2)=(1024,1024)`  `0.66ms`

`(N1,N2)=(2048,2048)`  `2.18ms`
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayFire uses just in time compiler for element wise operations (this includes arithmetic, logical, trignometric and other math operations).

This means something like

```
D_D = A_D + B_D + C_D + 3.;
```

is stored as an expression until the value of D_D is requested by the user or another non-jit function.

You can force evaluation of these expressions if you use the `af::eval()` function or the `eval()` method.

So for your particular problem, please use `D_D.eval()`  for both methods. You will need to do `af::sync()` also for the first method. `timeit()` does not need to be synchronized explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have applied your suggestions, but it seems I have still problems. I have further edited my post to present the latest results. It seems that, if I "increase the amount" of GPU warm-up, then I obtain more reasonable results. Are those the definitive timings. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @JackOLantern I should have mentioned that. The first approach needs to be warmed up once (the just in time compiler needs to generate the required kernel). Also add an `af::sync()` before the first `timer::start()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post with the new results including the additional `af::sync()` you recommended. They look reasonable, as the timing increases with the vectors' size. But should I now do any action for the `timeit` case (second approach) to obtain similar results? I do still get a constant timing of `2ms`. Thanks in advance for any further help.